# ¿Como saco los botones con ciclo for en tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

¿Cómo me puedo ahorrar todas estas lineas de código con un ciclo `for`:

```
Boton_7 = Button(frame, text='7', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('7')).place(x=25, y=262, width=52, height=40)
Boton_8 = Button(frame, text='8', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('8')).place(x=78, y=262, width=52, height=40)
Boton_9 = Button(frame, text='9', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('9')).place(x=131, y=262, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Del = Button(frame, text=u'\u232B', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: borran_un_caracter_pantalla('DEL')).place(x=184, y=262, width=52, height=40)
Boton_AC = Button(frame, text='AC', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: borrar_pantalla('AC')).place(x=237, y=262, width=52, height=40)

Boton_4 = Button(frame, text='4', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('4')).place(x=25, y=303, width=52, height=40)
Boton_5 = Button(frame, text='5', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('5')).place(x=78, y=303, width=52, height=40)
Boton_6 = Button(frame, text='6', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('6')).place(x=131, y=303, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Exp = Button(frame, text='^', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: potenciacion('^')).place(x=184, y=303, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Raiz = Button(frame, text='√', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: radicacion('√')).place(x=237, y=303, width=52, height=40)

Boton_1 = Button(frame, text='1', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('1')).place(x=25, y=344, width=52, height=40)
Boton_2 = Button(frame, text='2', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('2')).place(x=78, y=344, width=52, height=40)
Boton_3 = Button(frame, text='3', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('3')).place(x=131, y=344, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Mult = Button(frame, text='x', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: multiplicacion('x')).place(x=184, y=344, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Div = Button(frame, text='÷', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: division('÷')).place(x=237, y=344, width=52, height=40)

Boton_0 = Button(frame, text='0', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: numero_pulsado('0')).place(x=25, y=385, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Punto = Button(frame, text='.', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: punto('.')).place(x=78, y=385, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Igual = Button(frame, text='=', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: enter('=')).place(x=131, y=385, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Sum = Button(frame, text='+', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: suma('+')).place(x=184, y=385, width=52, height=40)
Boton_Rest = Button(frame, text='-', font=('calibri', 12), bg='white', relief='raised', fg='black', bd=1, cursor='hand2', command=lambda: resta('-')).place(x=237, y=385, width=52, height=40)
```

Ya lo intenté con un ciclo for pero solo muestra el ultimo boton.

Comment: Bueno en este caso estas almacenando la función `Button` a una variable distinta, que imagino que utilizaras para un determinado botón. quizá por eso no te permite hacer un for. Si podrías añadir el código con un ciclo for, para ver cómo estas generandolo para que te devuelva el último como has comentado por favor.

Comment: Hola Eder, ten en cuenta que cada botón es localizado en un lugar distinto y tiene unaa calback (command) distinta asociada, no se si un for es buena idea en tu caso....

Comment: Gracias x los comentarios.